How big can a ruling-set-like set can be in this 3-regular balanced trees?
Let $(G,r)$ be a balanced 3-regular tree on $n$ nodes of depth $k$ (i.e. all nodes but leaves are of degree 3 and the leaves are at distance exactly $k$ from the root). Take some distance $T \ge 1$ as parameter. Forget the nodes at distance at most $T$ from the leaves for the problem. An other way to look at this would be to only consider the graph $G'$ induced by nodes at distance at most $k-T$ from $r$.
Call two nodes $a,b \in G'$ far enough if they are at distance at least $T+1$ in $G'$. A set $S \subset V(G')$ is sparse enough if all pairs of nodes in $S$ are far enough.
Question: By choosing $k$ to our advantage, how big can $max_{S \text{ is sparse}} |S|$ get?
As far as I know a sparse enough set is basically the same as a $T-$ruling set of $G'$. However I don't know how to handle the fact it is in $G'$ and not $G$. Also, in my field we don't care much about optimizing solutions so this is kind of new to me.
Note: by saying "choosing $k$ to our advantage" I mean to avoid small issues like having a set which is big but not sparse enough because only one vertex is a bit too close from others. Realistically, I will need to have $T=\theta(\log k)$, hence it is useless to think about $k$ going to the infinity when $T$ does not change much.
